# Only run SQL query if condition met

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write an 'idiot proof' SQL script that can be run by non-SQL literate users.

My idea is to have a couple of variables defined at the top of the script, then run particular queries based on those variable.

I'm testing on mySQL, but it will eventually run on SQL-Server.

In pseudo-code this is what I'm trying to do:

```
# Set matchThis to the value to match
SET @matchThis = "matchMe";

# Uncomment (remove the #) one of the two lines below to update or just view
#SET @update = "YES";
SET @update = "NO";

IF @update = "YES" {
    UPDATE myTable SET myColumn = "changed" WHERE matchVal = @matchThis;
} ELSE {
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE matchVal = @matchThis;
}
```

I want to do this entirely in SQL if there is a way.

I've seen guides on using `SELECT IF` etc but can't figure out how to achieve the above.

Comment: You want to grant a non-SQL literate user access to your server to execute SQL scripts? That sounds dangerous to say the least.

Comment: Put whatever sql you want in a procedure and run that.

Comment: @WeSt It's done at the moment with people actually manually editing tables. When I say non-SQL-literate, they do have some (varying levels of) ability, but scripting seems an obvious way to make things safer by ensuring only the right tables are tweaked...

Comment: Using one product to test SQL that targets the other isn't the best idea. There are differences that *will* bite you even in such simple cases. Parameter handling is different, Unicode support is different, procedural statements like `IF` are different. `SELECT IF` is the equivalent of `CASE` in SQL Server and is *not* used for conditional execution

Comment: @Panagiotis I realise that - the script won't be copied, I'm just playing with ideas on an offline dev machine before moving to the SQL-Server system to write the real thing. It's worked for me in the past as the scripts have never been complex enough to cause problems when re-writing.

Comment: As @Mihai suggested, the safest way is to put everything in a stored procedure and limit the users to specify the parameters. In that case, you maintain full control over the script.

Comment: Error handling is different. An idiot-proof script should be able to handle exceptions and that is completely different. Transaction processing is also different which can cause your script to behave differently in each machine

Comment: Scripting variables are also different. You can define script variables and pass their values using `sqlcmd` as shown in [Using SqlCmd with Scripting Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)

Comment: I quite like the stored Procedure approach.. am looking in to that now.. Although I thought this was going to be a simple one - SPs are more involved than I thought I'd have to go on this.

Comment: Testing on MySQL and running on SQL Server will simply not work. The two of them are just too different. Always test and develop on the DBMS you are using in production. Everything else is just wasted time

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know what you are saying, but when I only have to write Sal statements / scripts every 6 months or so it's actually very useful as a general syntax memory jogger to just play with the mysql box. As far as I am aware, other than having to DECLARE the variables in Sal-server, Gordon Linoff's solution below would work on both systems unaltered.

Comment: @FatMonk actually, even this is different. MySQL caches execution plans only for the duration of a session (ie connection). SQL Server [caches them until evicted](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx) due to memory pressure. This technique will hurt performance if used in a frequently used query or procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for MSSQL. I think that you got everything down but the syntax. I hope this helps/works.

```
DECLARE @matchthis AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @update AS VARCHAR(1)

SET @matchthis = 'matchme'
--@update can be Y or N. User changes this here.
SET @update = 'Y'

IF @update = 'Y'
    UPDATE mytable SET myColumn = 'changed' WHERE matchval = @matchthis
ELSE IF @update = 'N'
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE matchval = @matchthis
```

I didn't know whether to make the changed a variable, but if you wanted to make it a variable, follow the same syntax as for @matchthis (declare and set).

If you want to make this really idiot proof, I'd say the best thing to do is make a stored procedure so that users don't see the code, they just have the input box.

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here. One is why the `IF` statement doesn't work - because T-SQL doesn't have braces. The syntax is shown in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx).

The important question though is how to pass parameters to the script without having the users modify the script itself. This is done using [Script Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx). When a script is executed by using the `sqlcmd` command, any text of the form `$(SomeName)` is replaced with command-line parameters or environment variables with the same name.

For example, if you have the following script

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
SELECT x.$(ColumnName)
FROM Person.Person x
WHERE c.BusinessEntityID < 5;
```

This command will run it with `FirstName` as the column name

```
sqlcmd -v ColumnName ="FirstName" -i c:\testscript.sql
```

Comment: I realise that the IF syntax is completely incorrect in my original post. That's why I refer to it as pseudo-code. I'm hoping Gordon Linoff has me on the right track now though...

Answer (score 1):

You are quite optimistic if you want to get a script that will run the same in MySQL and SQL Server.  However, for your basic script, you can do this:

```
-- Set matchThis to the value to match
SET @matchThis = 'matchMe';

-- Uncomment (remove the #) one of the two lines below to update or just view
-- SET @update = 'YES';
SET @update = 'NO';

UPDATE myTable
    SET myColumn = 'changed'
    WHERE matchVal = @matchThis AND @update = 'YES';

SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE matchVal = @matchThis AND @update <> 'YES';
```

This is *slightly* different from your script.  This actually runs the `select` if `@update` is `'YES'`, but it will not return any rows.

Two notes:

- SQL Server does not use double quotes for string constants.
- MySQL does not allow `if` statements, except in stored programs.
- The standard mechanism for commenting out a line is two hyphens (`--`)

If you need a script to run in T-SQL, you should develop it using T-SQL.

Comment: This is the closest so far to what I'm trying to achieve. However when I add the 'AND @update...' to the where clause I get no rows returned...

Comment: @FatMonk What is the value of `update`? If it's null, then the check fails as any comparison to null fails. Also note that such syntax is only suitable for scripts. SQL Server caches the execution plan of a command/stored procedure the first time it's used. If a subsequent call causes radically different behaviour, the cached execution plan may not be suitable and will result in inefficient queries

Comment: @FatMonk . . . Bummer, I missed that.  You can't use variables either.  SQL Server requires `declare`.  MySQL only allows `declare` in program blocks.  Nix that idea.  Do the development on SQL Server.

Comment: Oddly using `...AND @update LIKE 'YES';` and `...AND @update NOT LIKE 'YES';` seems to work.